# Quick search the most similar objects in the n-dimensional space

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, index, optimization

Lets assume that we have a points in the n-dimensional space. So we have a n coords(n columns) which can describe location of the each point.

**We need to implement a table which can be used for a quick searching the most similar points, i.e. points which have the smallest distance to the desired point.**

E.g. points in the db:

```
id  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
1   5   19  42  12  16
2   3   23  38  15  12
3   14  21  32  33  1
4   12  29  21  24  5
```

If we want to find the best matching for point with coords:

```
c1 c2  c3  c4  c5
4  20  40  14  15
```

We will get points with id 1 and 2.

We also have mean coordinate for each dimension(column) and vector for each point in which first element - number of the dimension in which point has the largest difference from the mean coordinate in this dimension, and last - number of the dimension in which point has the smallest difference. Maybe it can be used for the more rapid filtering points which have the biggest distance to the desired point.

**So how can I do something like this using MySQL?**

I think the composite index and `order by abs(cx - $mycx)` can be a good solution, but I can't use it because I will have more then 16 columns which I need to include in the one index.

Any help will be very useful!

Comment: Mathematically, the (Euclidean) distance would actually be calculated as `SQRT((c1-$myc1)^2 + (c2-$myc2)^2 + …)`.

Comment: @AndriyM I know but it will take a lot of time for big dataset, and we don't need so high accuracy

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245001/quick-search-the-most-similar-objects-in-the-n-dimensional-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PostgreSQL using [`cube`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html)

Using PostgreSQL this becomes pretty easy with [the `cube` extension which I explained on your other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163915/2639).. Sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
  (1, cube(ARRAY[5 , 19, 42, 12, 16]) ),
  (2, cube(ARRAY[3 , 23, 38, 15, 12]) ),
  (3, cube(ARRAY[14, 21, 32, 33, 1 ]) ),
  (4, cube(ARRAY[12, 29, 21, 24, 5 ]) )
) AS t(id, c);
```

Finding distance...

```
SELECT
  id,
  c,
  c2,
  cube_distance(c,c2),
  rank() OVER (ORDER BY cube_distance(c,c2))
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT cube(ARRAY[4,20,40,14,15]) )
  AS t(c2)
ORDER BY cube_distance(c, c2);
```

Outputs.

```
 id |          c          |         c2          |  cube_distance   | rank 
----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+------
  1 | (5, 19, 42, 12, 16) | (4, 20, 40, 14, 15) |  3.3166247903554 |    1
  2 | (3, 23, 38, 15, 12) | (4, 20, 40, 14, 15) | 4.89897948556636 |    2
  4 | (12, 29, 21, 24, 5) | (4, 20, 40, 14, 15) | 26.5706605111728 |    3
  3 | (14, 21, 32, 33, 1) | (4, 20, 40, 14, 15) | 26.8700576850888 |    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  (In the absence of further info, I prefer this solution.)

```
ORDER BY 
    ABS(c1 - $c1) +
    ABS(c2 - $c2) +
    ABS(c3 - $c3) +
    ABS(c4 - $c4) +
    ABS(c5 - $c5)  ASC
```

Or "root mean square" (without the unnecessary SQRT):

```
ORDER BY 
    (c1 - $c1) * (c1 - $c1) +
    (c2 - $c2) * (c2 - $c2) +
    ...  ASC
```

For finding the 'closest' item to a *single* query ($c1, $c2, ...), that takes a single pass over the data.  If the data is huge, it will be I/O-bound, so disk speed becomes the ruling constraint.  The squares will be only trivially slower than `ABS()`, so pick the metric you prefer.  (Note:  Using `POW(, 2)` might be noticeable slower.)

No index is of any use in this query.

You could add `LIMIT 10` to get the 10 "closest".  If you want to find all of those with exactly the same metric (and closest), the code becomes a lot messier and slower.

Plan B:  If the numbers "work right", it *may* be possible to use an index on *one* column.  In doing so, you would first find rows that are "close" to the value in that column.  (This list should not exceed 10% of the table.)  Then use the above code to laboriously go through that subset of rows.  The risk is that the *other* columns may be very close, while *this column* is too far to be filtered by the first pass.

Plan C is useful for finding the [*nearest pizza parlors*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng), but it does not extend beyond 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About plan A: if we will have big dataset I think search will take a lot of time. So it's main big problem, maybe a KD-tree can be a good solution?

Comment: Or maybe an R-Tree?

Comment: [1 part] I still can't find the answer. Unfortunately, KD-tree is not a good solution for a data with a many dimensions(I will have more than 120 dimensions), maybe I can use something like your solution but improve it using preliminary sorting? Every record has dimension with the biggest diference from the mean coordinate of this dimension(I have described it better in the question). So we can filter 50% the most closest records by the coord with the biggest difference, then filter 50% from previous query by the coord with the the second largest difference and so on.

Comment: [2 part] Also please check [this question which describe current question better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272915/quick-search-of-the-face-descriptors-in-the-db).

Comment: 50%, etc -- Aren't you are still stuck with touching every row in the dataset?  I assume this is the main performance issue.  (Computations are a lot cheaper than fetching rows.)