# Quick nearest neighbor search in the 150-dimensional space

Tags: database-design, performance, nearest-neighbor

I want to create a database using any of the possible RDBMS. It will have a table with approximately 150 columns. The objective is to perform nearest neighbor search of some other objects. So it's a NNS in the 150-dimensional space.

I already tried to use some obvious methods like L1 or L2 distances but of course it takes a lot of time for tables with many rows. Also I tried to look at the KD-tree (note I did not test it) and PG-Strom but they are not a good solution for data with a many dimensions.

Can I somehow improve the speed of the described search using math methods (like KD-tree) or tech methods (like PG-Strom)?

I will try to use any RDBMS which allow to improve speed of the NNS. But MySQL and PostgreSQL are the most appropriate DBMS for me.

Comment: These are other problems. Simply ask another question @don-prog

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## PostgreSQL 9.6 using [`cube`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html)

First install the [cube extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html)

```
CREATE EXTENSION cube;
```

Now we will create some n-dimensional space with 100,000 points in 50 dimensions. In addition we'll add a GIST index.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE space_nd
AS
  SELECT i, cube(array_agg(random()::float)) AS c
  FROM generate_series(1,1e5) AS i
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(1,50)
    AS x
  GROUP BY i;

CREATE INDEX ON space_nd USING gist ( c );
ANALYZE space_nd;
```

Now we will generate a single point and use the `<->` operater to find the nearest point using Eucledian distance.

```
WITH points AS (
  SELECT cube(array_agg(random()::float)) AS c
  FROM generate_series(1,50)
    AS x
)
SELECT i,
  pg_typeof(space_nd.c),
  pg_typeof(points.c),
  cube_distance(space_nd.c, points.c)
FROM space_nd
CROSS JOIN points
ORDER BY space_nd.c <-> points.c
LIMIT 5;
```

PostgreSQL 9.6+ supports other distance operators over `cube`. All of which can use the GIST index we created. Namely,

```
a <-> b float8  Euclidean distance between a and b.
a <#> b float8  Taxicab (L-1 metric) distance between a and b.
a <=> b float8  Chebyshev (L-inf metric) distance between a and b.
```

That said there is one caveat,

> To make it harder for people to break things, **there is a limit of 100 on the number of dimensions of cubes. This is set in cubedata.h if you need something bigger.**

You ask for 150 dimensions. That may present a minor complication.

Comment: The edit to `cubedata.h` doesn't work past 130 dimensions in my experience. Maybe you can also change all the `double`s or `float8`s in the extension to `float4`, since Postgres has a limit on per-row index size that you can stay away from by halving how many bytes you use on each number. I did some testing and got more dimensions in that way, and IIRC I got past 150, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: I had same problem with limit on dimensions and created docker image with 2048 limit: https://hub.docker.com/r/expert/postgresql-large-cube

Answer (score 2):

Consider performing dimension reduction first (eg. Principle Component Analysis).

Then your are doing NN in small number of dimensions with higher performance.

You can use Pl/R to perform PCA inside postgres if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FLANN and OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html).

Unfortunately I am not aware of an integration of that into a RDBMS system. But there is for example [integration of chemical structure information](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cartridge.html) with Posgres. So in principle this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/a-mma/AquilaDB it is a vector database to store Feature Vectors along with JSON Metadata. Keep it along with your RDBMS and do use metadata to maintain cross reference between data.