# KNN search two arrays with 2000 elements

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgis, nearest-neighbor

**What I did:**

1. installed postgresql 9.3.1
2. installed postgis 2.1.2
3. I tried to find the distance by selecting column input_variable_1 with value 50.

I got the following result.

```
select input_variable_1 <-> 50  as distance  from test_ata limit 10;
 distance 
       48
        2
       17
       29
       44
       37
       45
       17
       49
        2
(10 rows)
```

**what i want:**

*input*: column which stores array values say 2000 elements in a single record.

I came across cube extension and postGIS there i can get distance between two points by using tree and distance concepts for lower dimentsions upto 100.

1. How to find the distance between two arrays having elements atleast 2000 in postgresql?
2. which tree is best for 2000 dimension indexing in postgresql?
3. finally i want to know how to use KNN search in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

You have one option, you can recompile the `cube` extension to use more than 100 dimensions

KNN Search is done with PostGIS using the `<->` operator on two points. You can find out [how to do that in the docs.](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html). It doesn't operate in Nd-space. PostGIS isn't an abstract library for math. It's for real world geospatial problems. KNN in 1d, and 4d+ is not a real world problem, or at least not in the domain that PostGIS would be interested in.

I would suggest checking out my other answer here,

- [*Searching in n-dimensional space*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/163915/2639)

Comment: 1.first convert your array into cube(array)                                                                                       2.apply cube_distance to the converted array                                                             3.apply sorting u may get nearest values